# How do I fix this strange error when trying to integrate admobs into my app?

Tags: android, gradle, admob

I am trying to integrate admob into my app but I keep getting this strange error that says

> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zza found
>   in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.6.2-runtime.jar

(com.google.android"attached is my build.gradle file.

(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.2"[image: gradle file]

Answer (score 0):

The error usually appears when one of the modules that you include in your project has inside another library that you are including in your main project as well. My recommendation is to first update the version of the libraries that are highlighted. Then try to remove this and check if everything works:

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'`

Or if you have access to the gradle file of the module remove 'play-services-ads' there